# Symfony2 doctrine objects - why is a newly created object null?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have the following code in a controller action:

```
public function someAction()
{
    // ...
    $promo_repo = $em->getRepository('AcmeContactlistBundle:Promotion');
    $default_promo_code = $this->container->getParameter('promo_default_code');
    $promo = $promo_repo->findOneByCode($default_promo_code);

    if (empty($promo)) {
        $promo = new Promotion();
        $promo->setCode($default_promo_code);
        $start_date  = $this->container->getParameter('promo_default_start_date');
        $expiry_date = $this->container->getParameter('promo_default_end_date');
        $promo->setStartsAt(new \DateTime($start_date));
        $promo->setExpiresAt(new \DateTime($expiry_date));
        $em->persist($promo);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->setPromotion($promo); // <-  Error here. See error msg below

    // Some more code follows ...
}
```

**Error Message**

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   Acme\ContactlistBundle\Entity\Contact::setPromotion() must be an
>   instance of Acme\ContactlistBundle\Entity\Promotion, null given,
>   ...

I have checked the SQL generated by the above statements and also checked to make sure that a record is persisted to the promotion table (if not present). The promotion object is created and persisted to the database correctly, so I don't understand that by the times it comes to assigning it to the contact variable, it has a value of null.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that error happens in your controller? Make sure (based on exception's backtrace) if error happens in controller (for example maybe you try give null value to promotion in Contact entity's constructor?)

Comment: Don't use empty(), use if (!$promo) { ...

Comment: @Cerad: That's a red herring since `empty()` [returns true for null](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: Nope nope nope.  Read the manual.  empty checks for the existence of a variable, not if the variable has a value of null.  But I do like herring.

Comment: @Cerad, you're wrong, `empty()` checks for an empty variable, quoted from the doc: "Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty". If you want to check for the **existence** of a variable, use `isset()`

Comment: I stand corrected.  Don't see how the posted code could be failing unless the error message is actually for a different line.